# SSRS Visual Studio Expression for : If TXTBOX empty dont show data in TXTBOX 2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, null, ssrs-expression

i have a report and the user has 2 text boxes if one text box is empty i want the other to not show anything 
is there an expression to do so ?
so if i have 
no data in a calculated field then i don't want to show anything in the other box, 
as currently it shows regardless if theirs data or not.
ive tried looking at IfNothing but as this is 
a condition baced on weather a seperate text box is populated then i dont think it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of the second textbox based on the data in the first in the following way.

In the second textbox create a new expression as follows

```
=iif(isnothing(ReportItems!txtSource.Value), "Nothing", "Something")
```

Where `txtSource` is the name of the textbox you wish to inspect for data.  When the value of `txtSource` is equivalent to null, in the example above `Nothing` is displayed, otherwise `Something`